# Symfony How To Remove A File

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems

Why cant I use unlink() in Symfony?

I have tried this:

```
unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/web/account_assets/data/suppliers/file.txt)
```

I keep getting the same reponse: Warning: unlink(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/web/account_assets/data/suppliers/wordpress.txt): Permission denied in...

What Do I need to do???

I have set the permissions to 777 on this file.

Comment: The `unlink()` function does not have anything to do with Symfony. Also, you need to put the path in quotes (i.e. `unlink('/path/to/file')`). As for the "Permission denied" error, have you looked at its permissions and who owns the file? `ls -la` will show you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a permissions issue on main directory that contained the files. Once I changed the owner and permissions, all worked well. The filesystem component works awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can use the [remove](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#remove) function of the [filesystem component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html). If you don't want to use the filesystem component, that's fine, you can use `unlink()`, there is a great example in this [remove function of the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html):

```
public function removeUpload()
{
    if (isset($this->file)) {
        unlink($this->file);
    }
}
```

Now, the main problem is that you don't have permission to delete this file. You'd have to configure the directory like this in your virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/web/"
    ServerName yoursite.dev
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/web/account_assets/data/">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```