# Sympfony2 deleting file by name or path using Filesystem

Tags: php, image, symfony

Please suggest how to simply remove a file/image using filesystem.
The documentation on the symfony website is not clear as it mentions some array...

I tried this:

```
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->remove('name.jpeg');
```

and:

unlink('name.jpeg');

I also read this, but it did not help:

[Symfony How To Remove A File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448668/symfony-how-to-remove-a-file)

I also tried using the path, and path+name. but perhaps there is a special way of getting the path.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be the way you get the path:

```
$path = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../folder1/folder2/name.jpeg';

$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->remove($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get the absolute path of your resource, the options are :

Retrieve the kernel service :

```
$kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
```

For a bundle resource :

```
$path = $kernel->locateResource('@NameOfBundle/Resources/public/name.jpeg');
```

For other resource :

```
// Get the absolute path of your `app` directory
$rootDir = $kernel->getRootDir(); 
// Retrieve the resource
$path = $rootDir . '/../web/name.jpeg';
```

And then, remove it like you have already done using symfony/filesystem :

```
$fs = new Filesystem();

if ($fs->exists($path)) { // This check is useless if you used $kernel->locateResource() previously
    $fs->remove($path);
}
```

Hope this help you.